# How can I redirect to an error page in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, error-handling, routes

I am loading data from a JSON and I want to redirect to an error page, if the data is not available.

I tried `$location.path("404")`, but I always get an error message:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined".

directive:

```
myApp.directive("wfDependency", function(countTaskService,WorkflowRuns) {
  return {
    some d3 code in here...
  }
  $scope.$watch("workflowPath", function(wfPath, wfPath_old) {              
    d3.json("json/workflows/"+$scope.workflowPath+".json", function(error, data, $location) {
      if(error){
       console.log("ERROR");
       $location.path("/404");
      }else{
        $scope.data = data;
        createGraph();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

myApp:

```
let myApp = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute", "ngResource"])
  .config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/404", {
      templateUrl: "views/404.htm"
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to inject `$location` in your directive.

```
myApp.directive("wfDependency", function($location, countTaskService, WorkflowRuns) ...
```